# How to fix "trouble processing BuildConfig.class" in android?

Tags: android, zxing

I have some android app where I'm have zxing-android-embedded, but when I try to run my app I receiving next error:

```
    Error:trouble processing "com.android.example/BuildConfig.class":
    Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
    Error:when not building a core library.
    Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
    Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
    Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
    Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
    Error:going on.
    Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
    Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
    Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
    Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
    Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
    Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
    Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
    Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
    Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
    Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
    Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
    Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
    Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
    Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
    Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
    Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
    Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
    Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
    Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
    Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
    Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
    Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
    Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
    Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
    Error:1 error; aborting
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}
```

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was in my package name. It was "java.org.example".
I've changed it and everything works now.